# Resizing array of numpy images

Tags: numpy, opencv, reshape

I have 60,000 images with 28x28 shape and 1 channel.

```
images.shape
# (60000, 300, 300, 1)
```

So, I want to reshape all the images, say, to 35x35. So, the shape should be:

```
# (60000, 500, 500, 1)
```

What I tried is I reshaped every single image one by one and than concatenated them:
images:

```
import cv2

images = np.reshape(x_test, (60000, 300, 300))

new_images = []
for img in images:
    new_images.append(cv2.resize(img, (500, 500), interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA))

new_images = np.array(new_images)
new_images = np.reshape(new_images, (60000, 500, 500, 1))
```

**But it's taking long time. Is there any more effitient/faster/convenient way of doing this?**

Comment: please distinguish between "resizing/resampling", which changes the amount of data in an array, and "reshaping", which doesn't change it but reassigns the dimensions.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz, thanks a lot, I updated my question :)

Comment: If you have a multicore processor I'd recommend using `multiprocessing` to distribute the resizing. Or if you have a gpu that supports CUDA you could consider using that (e.g. with pytorch).

Comment: This is a pure Numpy question, and has actually nothing to do with `deep-learning` or `computer-vision` - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Answer (score 0):

currently you resize your data every time after you load it. you should resize/resample your data once, then save that version of your data, and load that version instead.

you can save your whole array using numpy's `np.save`. that may go faster than loading individual images, which may need to be decoded too. with numpy you have the choice of saving compressed (.npz, `np.savez`) or uncompressed (.npy). uncompressed takes more space (so that can slow you down) but doesn't require compression/decompression.